# Is it possible to move properties definition from the configuration to the resources?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, properties, configuration

I have the following sessionFactory Bean definition:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.badmitrii.db.entity.Employee</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- Here is a crowd of props -->
        </props>            
    </property>
</bean>
```

I think it would be unconvinient to put all of the properties I need into the spring configuration file. Is there a way to move the crowd of props into a separate resource file and apply it load the bean?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://kh-yiu.blogspot.hk/2013/08/spring-injecting-properties-file-values.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [configLocations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setConfigLocations-org.springframework.core.io.Resource...-) LocalSessionFactoryBean property and configure it to where the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file is located:

```
classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml
```

The `hibernate.cfg.xml` will contain all your Hibernate properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```